# Tcl List output modification

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a list named "a" and need to perform some basic list operations and commands to get the desired result in another list "b"

This list "a" can contain more elements in any order I have shown one example below

```
(%) set a {{123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]}} mno}

 {{123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]} mno}
```

Currently, I tried this and got

```
(%) set b ""
(%)    
(%) foreach l $a {
       lappend b [regsub -all [lindex $l 0] $l ""]
    }
(%) puts $b

 {{p_q[5]}} {{r_s[6]}} {}
```

Instead I want "b" to have output as follows

```
p_q[5] r_s[6] mno
```

Tcl version: 8.4.6

Comment: What do you want to archive? Mixing lists and strings is never a good idea. You use $l as list (`lindex $l 0`)  and as string `regsub ... $l`

Comment: @Johannes Kuhn: I want to achieve output for list b as written in my last line of the question, that is expected. Next time I will try not mix lists and strings

Comment: @user2643899 if any answer helps and satisfy the question. There is an option to accept the answer.

Comment: You are aware that 8.4.6 is _vastly_ out of date? There are later patches to the 8.4 series; it's up to 8.4.20 now (and you'll need commercial support to go later). That's totally backward compatible, except with many bugs fixed. Or you could switch to 8.5 (now 8.5.15) or 8.6 (now 8.6.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Here is again one liner for you:

```
% set a {{123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]}} mno}
  {123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]}} mno
% set b [lsearch -all -regexp -not -inline [regsub -all "\{|\}" $a ""] ":"]
{p_q[5]} {r_s[6]} mno
```

If further, you want to remove {}, then

```
%set b [regsub -all "\{|\}" $b ""]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution, if I understand your problem correctly:

```
set a {{123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]}} mno}
puts $a

set b [list]
foreach item $a {
    lappend b [lindex $item end]
}
puts ">$b<"
set b [concat {*}$b]
puts ">$b<"
```

Output:

```
{123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]}} mno
>{p_q[5]} {r_s[6]} mno<
>p_q[5] r_s[6] mno<
```

## Discussion

1. The loop goes through each item in list `a`
2. For each item, pick out the last sub-item and append it to `b`
3. After the list exits, `b` is almost what you want (see the second line in the output)
4. A call to `concat` will fix that to your liking.

## Update

Donal Fellows pointed out that instead of using `[concat {*}$b]`, I can use `[join $b]`. This approach has a couple of advantages which I like:

- It works on older 8.4 systems, which does not support the `{*}` construct
- It is simpler to understand

However, the `concat` approach offers an advantage: speed. Take a look at the following interactive session:

```
(Downloads2) 61 % set b {{p_q[5]} {r_s[6]} mno}
{p_q[5]} {r_s[6]} mno
(Downloads2) 62 % time {concat {*}$b} 10000
0.43452700000000005 microseconds per iteration
(Downloads2) 63 % time {join $b} 10000
0.603005 microseconds per iteration
```

The `concat` speed is about 30% faster than `join` in this case.

Comment: Which version of tcl are you using, because I tried the exact same code that you have and I am getting the following error

Comment: {123.4:xyz {p_q[5]}} {123.4:abc {r_s[6]}} mno
>{p_q[5]} {r_s[6]} mno<
extra characters after close-brace
    while executing
"set b [concat {}$b]
puts ">$b<"
"
    (file "t.tcl" line 9)

Comment: You might prefer to use `[join $b]` instead of `[concat {*}$b]` to remove the braces. That works with 8.4 too.

Comment: @Donal, I did not know think about `join`. Thank you for pointing it out. At work, we still have some systems with 8.4, so this is a great tip. For 8.5 and later, I prefer `concat` because it is faster. See my update.